# Number of Comparisons Made by a Binary Search

Tags: java, search, count, binary

Is it possible to count the number of comparisons made by a recursive binary search? If so, how?

Here is the search I am referring to:

```
//binary search
public static int binarySearch(int[] items, int start, int end, int goal)
{
    if (start > end)
        return (-1);
    else
    {
        int mid = (start + end)/2;
        if (goal == items[mid])
            return (mid);
        else
        if (goal < items[mid])
            return (binarySearch(items, start, mid - 1, goal));
        else
            return (binarySearch(items, mid + 1, end, goal));
    }
}//end binarySearch
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your count variable outside of the method. Then add 1 each time that you call the method.

```
long count = 0;
//binary search
public static int binarySearch(int[] items, int start, int end, int goal)
{
    count += 1
    if (start > end)
        return (-1);
    else
    {
        int mid = (start + end)/2;
        if (goal == items[mid])
            return (mid);
        else
        if (goal < items[mid])
            return (binarySearch(items, start, mid - 1, goal));
        else
            return (binarySearch(items, mid + 1, end, goal));
     }
}//end binarySearch
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using a `long`?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I prefer durable code, but as you seem to be indicating, yes, a binary search is unlikely to need long unless the size of your search space well exceeds 10^50 or some equally large number. It doesn't have a significant performance overhead given that `count` is only initialized once.

Comment: It's not only unlikely but impossible as the parameters defining the range are `int`s, not to mention the fact that a binary search runs in log time or better. Even with a `long` range you would only really need a `byte count`. But I think `int` is most readable for just your average integer value.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Yeah, it's force of habit. I've coded enough timers and searches that I instinctively declare count variables as long. Thanks for the tip and I'll do my best to keep my instinct at bay. It seems relying on instinct is a bit of a gamble; it takes serious experience for it to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely approach if you want to caller to be able to access the count is to pass in an accumulator into your binary search.  In java 7 or less, AtomicLong may be a good choice (though it does have some overhead).  In java 8, a LongAdder would also be good:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] items, int start, int end, int goal, AtomicLong counter) {

}
```

and each time you do a comparison, you would just increment the count:

```
counter.incrementAndGet()
```

When you exit the search, the counter will contain the number of comparisons:

```
long count = counter.get()
```